# Connecting a Magellan RoadMate to a computer

Tags: laptop, usb, gps

After reading [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/14078/hooking-up-a-magellan-maestro-gps-mm3225-to-my-laptop-to-get-location-informati)...

Is it possible to connect a Magellan RoadMate (1200, to be specific) to a computer? I have an USB cable, but when I connect the device to my laptop, it isn't recognized by the OS (that is, neither Ubuntu's `/var/log/syslog` nor Windows' Device Manager show anything at all). The device is based on Windows CE Core 5.0 (or so it says on the back).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a dumb question, but did it come with any drivers?

Though that doesn't necessarily solve your recognition problem...

Some people suggest that your cable is crap, bad wiring or something. Perhaps try another mini-USB cable?

[I found something on a different device that had similar problems:](http://forums.groundspeak.com/GC/lofiversion/index.php?t169809.html)

> From Magellan:
>
> Thank you for contacting Magellan.
>   This email is in response to your
>   query about the Explorist 210.
>
> I understand that you are having
>   difficulties in getting the unit
>   detected on your computer.
>
> Before you start doing these steps
>   please check with the operating system
>   in your PC. Because only WINDOWS XP,
>   2000 would be compatible with
>   Magellan. MACINTOSH would not be
>   compatible with Magellan.
>
> 1. Connect the USB cable to the Explorist unit in such a way that the
>      USB cable is pointing downwards
>      towards the battery case.
> 2. Make sure that the unit is put up in the file transfer mode. After
>      connecting the USB cable to the unit
>      press menu and press enter in the file
>      transfer mode.
> 3. Make sure that you have connected the USB cable to the rear port and not
>      to the front port of the PC. Then your
>      unit would be detected as a new
>      hardware under "Removable disk E:\ or
>      G:\ or F:\"
> 4. If you have any external devices like web cam or printer connected to
>      the USB port please remove them.
> 5. Also if you have any firewall or antivirus enabled in your PC please go
>      ahead and disable them. Then restart
>      your PC.
> 6. Then remove the USB cable from your unit and power off the unit and then
>      connect the USB cable and then power
>      on the unit.
>
> If the issue still persists, and If
>   you could not install the CD then I
>   would suggest you to please give a
>   call to the technical support
>   department number 1-800-707-9971 so
>   that we would walk you through the
>   trouble shooting steps to fix this
>   issue.
>
> If you have further queries, please
>   get back to us.
>
> You can also contact our Technical
>   Support at 1-800-707-9971 for further
>   assistance.
>
> Regards, Steve  Magellan Email
>   Support.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to connect Magellan GPS to laptop by following steps shown below;

1. remove SD card from top slot (recording slot) to the slot on the left (reading slot) and then connect Magellan RoadMate GPS to laptop using USB cable.
2. After that you have to open MiVue app on the laptop and click on Folder icon on the top left on the menu bar,
3. Then in the Browse for Folders box, go to Removable Disk (G:).
4. Select Normal or Parking Folder and click Open.
5. The MiVue shows the video
6. Click Play to play videos in that folder
7. You can then save the video to laptop by selecting Save icon on top menu bar.

Sach

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue.  Make sure you are using a compatible browser.  It won't connect using Google Chrome and make sure it's the actual browser from the internet and not app based.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this, or maybe provide a link to further reading?  Thanks.

Comment: _Browser_? I think you're replying to the wrong question there...